# Googple Maps API. Не загружается асинхронно карта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Карта почему то не загружается асинхронно и в лайтхаусе выдает предупреждение. Как это починить?
Вот сам код. Загрузка API ключа идет в блоке head

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
```

сам скрипт идет перед закрывающим тегом бади

```
<script src="js/google-map.js"></script>
 </body>
```

. Вот код самого скрипта

```
function initMap() {

    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opt);

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
      position: pos,
      map: myMap,
      icon:'img/contacts/map-pin.svg'
    })

}
```

часть кода со стилями поудалял с функции. Вот что выдает лайтхаус [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Удалите слово defer из тега script